# Check Local Time Against Given Time In Another Time Zone

Tags: java, time, java-8, java-time

I am having trouble with some logic to check the local system time against a given time in another time zone.  Essentially all I need to do is take a scheduled call time and a specific time zone given to us in a contact list and check if the system time (which will always be Central Time) is equal to or after the scheduled call time in the given time zone.

So the timestamp comes in this format `06-03-2020 19:00:10` and there would be a timezone as well, for example, `Canada/Newfoundland`.  I feel like this should be a straightforward problem but I am having trouble getting it to work.  The following is the method as it is right now:

```
private boolean restrictTimeCheck1(String schedCallTime, String tz) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(Util.ts()) + ">>> Entering restrictTimeCheck1");
        boolean canCall = false;
        Date now = new Date();
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(now.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date schedDate = sdf.parse(schedCallTime );
        LocalDateTime schedTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(schedDate.toInstant(), ZoneId.of(tz));
        ZonedDateTime zonedSchedTime = schedTime.atZone(ZoneId.of(tz));
        if (ldt.isAfter(zonedSchedTime.toLocalDateTime())) {
            canCall = true;
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(Util.ts()) + "<<< Exiting restrictTimeCheck1: " + canCall);
        return canCall;
      }
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you can use `LocalDateTime`, `Instant`, `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, I recommend that you avoid mixing in `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. One, those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Two, using both sets of classes just overcomplicates things. java.time gives you all the functionality you could wish for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fairly simple:

```
ZonedDateTime scheduledCallTime = LocalDateTime
        .parse("06-03-2020 19:00:10", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss"))
        .atZone(ZoneId.of("Canada/Newfoundland"));

ZonedDateTime localSystemTime = ZonedDateTime.now();

System.out.println("Scheduled Call Time: " + scheduledCallTime);
System.out.println("Local System Time: " + localSystemTime);
System.out.println("You're late: " + localSystemTime.isAfter(scheduledCallTime));
```

*Output*

```
Scheduled Call Time: 2020-03-06T19:00:10-03:30[Canada/Newfoundland]
Local System Time: 2020-03-08T15:37:00.836235400-04:00[America/New_York]
You're late: true
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works now, I think I was just way overthinking/engineering this.